# Octave (Matlab): Spectrum calculation

Tags: fft, octave, spectrum, audacity

another question about spectrum calculation in Octave using FFT:

With Audacity I created a .wav file containing white noise, then filtered with a lowpass with fcut = 1kHz, -20dB/decade. The spectrum analysed by Audacity looks as expected (unfortunately I can't post an image since I don't have enough reputation)

Then I analysed the spectrum with Octave using the following code:

```
  pkg load signal   %load signal package
  graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot")  % use gnuplots

  close all
  clear all

  [stereosig, fs,bit] =wavread('noise_stereo.wav'); % load wav
  ch1 = stereosig(:,1); % left
  ch2 = stereosig(:,2); % right

  NFFT = 1024;
  NFFT_half = NFFT/2;
  X = fft(ch1, NFFT);
  freqvect = (1:NFFT_half+1)./NFFT*fs;

  figure(1)
  X_mag_scaled = abs(X(1:NFFT_half+1)./NFFT_half);
  semilogx(freqvect, 20*log10(X_mag_scaled));
  grid on
  xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
  ylabel('Mag [dB]')
```

The plot produced by Octave is extremly "unsmooth", the -20dB/decade can not be recognised properly since the difference between two adjacent points can be > 10dB or so. The 1kHz cut off frequency can only be guessed.

Does anybody have an idea how to get a "smooth" spectrum as it is done in Audacity (which I suppose to be a reasonable solution)?

Philippe

Comment: You probably just need to increase `N`. If your sample rate is e.g. 44.1 kHz then with N = 1024 each point in you spectrum is around 40 Hz wide.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but that does not bring any improovement. The Audacity-Spectrum uses also just 1024 Samples.

Comment: Typically you want to apply a window function (hanning for example) before doing the fft.

Comment: Maybe you could include an example of each plot so that we can see the difference and get a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve ? (If you don't have enough rep then just add a link to each image and someone else can easily convert these to inline images.)

Comment: This is a "quick and dirty solution" but please find the two plots in my profile image. Upper image: The Octave-solution, lower image: the audacity solution with a rectangular window.